# How to change page type without losing past SEO value

Tags: seo, http-status-code-301

As time goes on we are sometimes required to change a page that is ranked well to a new page name. For instance, GreatInfo.asp   to be replaced by the same content but called GreatInfo.php

It's basically a 301 redirect but on the page level. I'm running Windows Server (IIS7) and can do full site 301 redirects but not clear on the same goal for a single page.

I researched this page but still it is not clear:
http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection

This page concludes in saying to simply paste code on your page to achieve the individual page 301 redirect:
http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/2007/03/how-to-properly-implement-a-301-redirect/
but yet no reference is given to such code..

So I would have to say my question is what code is used at a page level to do a single page 301 redirect?

Comment: Answer:301 redirects in PHP



    <?php
    header(“HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently”);
    header(“Location: http://www.example.com/”);
    ?>
Note: you’ll need to make sure you don’t echo out any HTML or text before executing these functions.
301 redirects in ASP

If you’re using ASP, it looks like this:

    <%
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.example.com/"
    Response.End
    %>


Now whether this retains any positive SEO ranking from the page setting the 301 redirect, I do not know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer:

301 redirects in PHP

In some cases, you can’t do it with .htaccess so you’re stuck doing it at the page level. If you need to do a 301 redirect in PHP, here’s how:

```
<?php
header(“HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently”);
header(“Location: http://www.example.com/”);
?>
```

Note: you’ll need to make sure you don’t echo out any HTML or text before executing these functions.
301 redirects in ASP

If you’re using ASP, it looks like this:

```
<%
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.example.com/"
Response.End
%>
```

Now whether this retains any positive SEO ranking from the page setting the 301 redirect, I do not know... Also I've not found the same page level methods for a static html page redirect. But at least for classic asp and php the methods above will work well.